# Formula to calculate required value to pass level

Tags: c#, math

I have the following formula to calculate the number of balls that need to be removed in order to advance to the next level. And every level has 5 more balls than the previous level.

```
    int level = Level.getLevel();
    int balls = level * 5;
    int required = (int)Mathf.Ceil(balls * 0.0275f * level);
```

I can't seem to figure out a good formula to use to calculate `required` without going over `balls` or where `balls != required`. So basically `balls` must always be less than `required`.

With what I have, at about level 37 `required > balls`, which makes beating the level impossible. What is a better formula that I could use?

Comment: You can add `Math.Min()` to your formula, so you take the minimum between `required` and `balls` or `balls - 1`.

Comment: How about `required = level * 6`? I don't see why this needs to be fancy.

Comment: @Kevin because it needs to start with a large gap between balls and required and slowly get closer together but never be the same or go over. And with that level 1 would be impossible with required = 6 and balls = 5

Comment: I'm confused. You originally said "balls must always be less than required". Which is it? Less than or greater than?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, choose a function which gives the fraction of the balls which are required. This should start near 0 and get closer to but still below 1. For example,

```
double frac;
if (level < 24)
  frac = level / 30.0;
else
  frac = 1.0 - 5.0/level;
```

Then simply compute the required number from that:

```
int balls = level * 5;
int required = (int)Math.Round(balls * frac);
```

Just in case you might want some guards:

```
if (required < 1)
  required = 1;
if (required >= balls)
  required = balls - 1;
```